# What is exports and prototype in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Javascript and am seeing a lot of usage of exports and prototype in the code that I read. What are they mainly used for and how do they work?

```
//from express
var Server = exports = module.exports = function HTTPSServer(options, middleware){
  connect.HTTPSServer.call(this, options, []);
  this.init(middleware);
};

Server.prototype.__proto__ = connect.HTTPSServer.prototype;
```

Comment: `export` keyword details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export). Currently it is not supported natively by any of the web-browsers.

Answer (score 23):

*Exports* is used to make parts of your module available to scripts outside the module. So when someone uses `require` like below in another script:

```
var sys = require("sys");
```

They can access any functions or properties you put in `module.exports`

The easiest way to understand prototype in your example is that `Server` is a class that inherits all of the methods of `HTTPSServer`. `prototype` is one way to achieve class inheritance in javascript.

Comment: but note that export, and modules in general, is not plain javascript, but an "extention" of node.js

Comment: Years went by and now it is a CommonJS modules pattern, not only for Node but in many other JavaScript environments. Including the browser thanks to polyfills and soon enough ES6 (the next JavaScript version)

Comment: @Yannick Loiseau `module` is `node` keyword And `export` is `javascript` keyword [javascript keyword list](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Comment: "is one way to achieve class inheritance in javascript." Are there more?

Answer (score 13):

[This](https://vimeo.com/18782160) video explains node.js module.exports and [here](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.prototype) is a resource which describes JavaScript prototype.

Comment: Thanks! That video was extremely helpful as well as the link.

Comment: The video link is now longer valid.  I believe it is now: http://nodetuts.com/05-modules.html

Comment: Please fix the first link!

Comment: @JimRush Those responsible for sacking the people who have just been sacked because of a broken link have been sacked. Is the one there now what you expected?