# top-level namespace and usage of exports of Backbone source code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, namespaces

I'm trying to read the source code of Backbone.js. I am quite perplexed by the following code, which is supposed to declare the top-level namespace of Backbone. Anyone can help give some clue or explanations? Some useful links to enlighten this is also very welcome!

```
// The top-level namespace. All public Backbone classes and modules will
  // be attached to this. Exported for both CommonJS and the browser.
  var Backbone;
  if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    Backbone = exports;
  } else {
    Backbone = root.Backbone = {};
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exports` is a CommonJS-pattern global (think require.js and node.js) that is used to provide code modularly. The top check is seeing if `exports` is available. If it is, the Backbone global is given the exports reference so it can be properly exported modularly.

If you are not loading Backbone through an AMD-style loader, it is defined by a standard object literal.

Further reading on the matter:

http://dailyjs.com/2010/10/18/modules/

[What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-nodejs-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

[What is exports and prototype in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380159/what-is-exports-and-prototype-in-javascript)

Further exposition:

`exports` itself carries some added "beefiness" beyond a normal object literal. This "beefiness" is required for the CommonJS modular pattern. Note here in the Node.js source:

```
function Module(id, parent) {
  this.id = id;
  this.exports = {};
  this.parent = parent;
  if (parent && parent.children) {
    parent.children.push(this);
  }

  this.filename = null;
  this.loaded = false;
  this.children = [];
}

module.exports = Module;
```

The `Backbone` global gets access to all of this tertiary depth necessary for the modular pattern. Otherwise, `Backbone` would simply start with a boring old empty `object` definition.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But I am not very clear about the meaning of "the Backbone global is given the exports reference so it can be properly exported modularly." Why use "Backbone = exports;" instead of "exports = root.Backbone" ?