# Using "Exports." in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, export

I'm a new coder and I'm trying to interpret `exports` in the following code:

```
exports.setCourse = function(c){
    course = c;
    Ti.API.debug('Setting course to ' + course.get('title'));
};
```

Whats the difference between `exports.setCourse=function(c)`  and just `setCourse=function (c)`?

Comment: Read here http://www.commonjs.org/specs/modules/1.0/

Comment: `export` keyword details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export). Currently it is not supported natively by any of the web-browsers.

Answer (score 9):

and welcome to the wonderful world of coding -- I hope you enjoy it.

`exports` is a node.js concept that declares the functions that your module makes available to code outside itself. It defines the module's interface.

Check out [this StackOverflow answer...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380159/what-is-exports-and-prototype-in-javascript)