# what is "exports" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-loader

when I study a vuejs example, I came across this line in a javascript file:

```
exports.getLastTimeStr = (time, friendly) => {
```

I only encountered javascript syntax such as "module.export" or "export default", I didn't see code like above. As a result, I got warning like:

```
11:15-20 "export 'default' (imported as 'utils') was not found in './libs/utils'
```

Googling led to this link: [Using "Exports." in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995901/using-exports-in-javascript)

it appears to be a commonJS stuff but I was unable to go further from here, nor a solution was found.

Comment: Initially, if you don’t reassign `module.exports`, it’s an empty object also called `exports`. Assigning to properties of `exports` is a short way of assigning to properties of `module.exports`. If you’re using ESM, use an ESM export instead – `export const getLastTimeStr = …`. (Note that it still needs to be imported correctly, like `import { getLastTimeStr } from …`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exports` points to the same object reference as `module.exports`.

From the code snippet in your question.

```
exports.getLastTimeStr = (time, friendly) => {
```

and

```
module.exports.getLastTimeStr = (time, friendly) => {
```

Both would mean the same because both have the same object reference.

Read more here [Difference between "module.exports" and "exports" in the CommonJs Module System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383795/difference-between-module-exports-and-exports-in-the-commonjs-module-system)